# Concatenate as A and choose either A or B according to their FKs

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables:

```
IDcontacts | FirstName | LastName
----------------------------------
1          | Walt      | Ne
```

```
IDcompany | CompanyName
------------------------
1         | Universe
```

```
IDowner  | IDcontacts | IDcompany
---------------------------------
1        | 1          | NULL
2        | NULL       | 1
3        | NULL       | NULL
```

I need a query that will give me the following output:

```
IDoutput | Name
--------------------
1        | Walt Ne
2        | Universe
3        | NULL
```

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm learning SQL on my own and some things aren't so obvious to me.

Comment: People at SO can be pretty hostile when you ask question this way so my hint for the future is to show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a join and get half a result even if the other record does not exist, use an outer join.

To chose the first non-NULL value of a list, use COALESCE:

```
SELECT IDowner as IDoutput,
       COALESCE(FirstName || ' '  || LastName, CompanyName) AS Name
FROM Owner
LEFT JOIN Contacts ON Owner.IDcontacts = Contacts.IDcontacts
LEFT JOIN Company  ON Owner.IDcompany  = Company .IDcompany
```